# kivy Bottom Toolbar et multi screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Two Things:
1 - I am wondering if this is the right way to achieve what i want. Persistent bottom Appbar when switching screen

2 - I dunno how to remove extra padding at the top of bottom AppBar. (white space between bottomAppBar and button, see below)

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_file("multi.kv")


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        # Create the screen manager
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))

        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

multi.kv

```
<MDBottomAppBar>:
    MDToolbar:
        title: "test"
        left_action_items : [["menu", lambda x: print("menu pressed")]]
        right_action_items : [["dots-vertical", lambda x: print("dots print")]]
        icon: 'account'
        icon_color : [1,0,0]

<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Goto settings'
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                    root.manager.current = 'settings'
            Button:
                text: 'Quit'
        MDBottomAppBar

<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'My settings button'
            Button:
                text: 'Back to menu'
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                    root.manager.current = 'menu'
        MDBottomAppBar
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a persistent `AppBar` by not inclding it in your `Screens`. You can have a `MainWindow` that contains the `ScreenManager` and the `MDBottomAppBar` by adding `MainWindow` to your `kv`:

```
<MDBottomAppBar>:
    MDToolbar:
        title: "test"
        left_action_items : [["menu", lambda x: print("menu pressed")]]
        right_action_items : [["dots-vertical", lambda x: print("dots print")]]
        icon: 'account'
        icon_color : [1,0,0,1]

<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Goto settings'
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                    root.manager.current = 'settings'
            Button:
                text: 'Quit'
        # MDBottomAppBar

<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'My settings button'
            Button:
                text: 'Back to menu'
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                    root.manager.current = 'menu'
        # MDBottomAppBar
        
<MainWindow>:
    ScreenManager:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: root.height - appbar.height
        y: appbar.top
        MenuScreen:
            name: 'menu'
        SettingsScreen:
            name: 'settings'
    MDBottomAppBar:
        id: appbar
```

And now the `build()` method just returns `MainWindow()`:

```
class TestApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()
```

Comment: Thank you, much more cleaner. But two things i had to create class for MainWindows with Screen for Inheritance ( with Widget everything is on the left with like 10% width and all 90% in white. dunno if its okey. and Last  in order to remove the white padding at the top : i did this :  ScreenManager:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: root.height
        y: appbar.top -  dp("37"). But i had to find 37 by my self. appbar.height seems to height